# Компиляция многофайлового проекта Java в отдельное место

Tags: java, компиляция

Как, используя `javac`, скомпилировать проект, чтобы откомпилированные файлы располагались не в директориях рядом с исходниками, а в отдельной папке, например, `/production`?

Например, есть исходники файлы:

```
./com/company/folder1/file11.java   
./com/company/folder1/file12.java
./com/company/folder2/file21.java
./com/company/folder2/file22.java  
./com/company/run/runner.java
```

Скомпилированные код должен лежать не рядом с исходниками, а в отдельной папке:

```
./production/com/company/folder1/file11.class   
./production/com/company/folder1/file12.class
./production/com/company/folder2/file21.class
./production/com/company/folder2/file22.class  
./production/com/company/run/runner.class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте параметр -d

```
javac -d <пуст к директории куда скомпилировать> <путь к вашему java-файлу>
```

Пример:

```
javac -d /production/com/company/folder1 /com/company/folder1/file11.java
```